# Problema com p:dataTable, ajax, ui:include

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou com um problema, tenho uma p:dataTable que não funciona o "sortBy", nem a paginação. Quando testo o código desta tabela em uma página simples ela funciona, porém quando utilizo ela no meu projeto ela não funciona. No meu projeto chamo a página que possui a tabela através de um  a tabela busca os dados do bean, porém não funciona nem a ordenação nem a paginação. Estou utilizando CDI com @Named, @ViewScope e @Inject, já testei com outros escopos e o resultado é o mesmo :(

Código da Tabela:

```
<h:form>    
<p:dataTable value="#{moduloController.modulos}" var="m" id="tabModulos"
                        emptyMessage="Nenhum módulo localizado." paginator="true" rows="10"
                        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                        <p:column  headerText="Nome" width="40%" sortBy="#{m.nome}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{m.nome}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column  headerText="Descrição" width="40%" sortBy="#{m.descricao}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{m.descricao}" />
                        </p:column>


                        <p:column headerText="Módulo Principal" width="20%" 
                            styleClass="align-center" sortBy="#{m.topModulo.nome}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{m.topModulo.nome}" />
                        </p:column>                 

                    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

A inserção da página que contêm a tabela é feita através do seguinte código:

```
            <h:panelGroup id="painelConteudo" layout="block">
                <ui:include src="#{menuController.pageLink}.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

Testando esse código da tabela em uma página comum ela funciona perfeitamente.

Comparando o debug, via pelo developer tools do Chrome percebi que na página que é feita a inclusão, o ajax não chama o elemento para atualização;

Segue o debug pelo página que não funciona:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
<changes>
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">-8477971442835400176:4133945171221710420</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

e agora o debug pela página simples... onde é possível visualizar a tabela a ser ordenada.

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
<changes>
<update id="form:j_idt14"><tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Administrativo</td><td role="gridcell">Módulo de Administração do Sistema</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center"></td></tr><tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Caixa</td><td role="gridcell">Gerencie o caixa</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center"></td></tr><tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Calendário</td><td role="gridcell">Agende seus compromissos</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center"></td></tr><tr data-ri="3" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Cargos</td><td role="gridcell">Cadastro de Cargos</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center">Administrativo</td></tr><tr data-ri="4" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell">CFOP</td><td role="gridcell">Cadastro de CFOP</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center">Administrativo</td></tr><tr data-ri="5" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Clientes</td><td role="gridcell">Cadastro de Clientes</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center">Administrativo</td></tr><tr data-ri="6" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Colaboradores</td><td role="gridcell">Cadastro de Colaboradores</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center">Administrativo</td></tr><tr data-ri="7" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Compras</td><td role="gridcell">Gerencie de compra de insumos e produtos</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center"></td></tr><tr data-ri="8" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Contas a Pagar</td><td role="gridcell">Gerencie as contas a pagar</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center"></td></tr><tr data-ri="9" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"><td role="gridcell">Contas a Receber</td><td role="gridcell">Gerencie as contas a receber</td><td role="gridcell" class="align-center"></td></tr></update>
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">4054556111108695514:3140532311518801280</update>
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"totalRecords":27}</extension>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

é como se o primefaces não estivesse localizando o form. Já coloquei o form dentro da página a ser incluída e também na página que faz a inserção, o resultado é o mesmo... ou seja não funciona a ordenação, nem a paginação neste caso. Alguém tem alguma sugestão sobre como resolver?

Comment: O código da tabela do include só tem isso que você postou ou tem alguma outra coisa?